# Jenkinsfile scripted parallel causes shell statement to fail

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

In my scripted Jenkinsfile I have a line that runs `parallel deployments` . I omitted the other stages and code for security.

When I run this, it can't find the `reportUrl` and  I get the error: `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: teamsUrl for class: groovy.lang.Binding`.

However, if I run without the `parallel deployments` it works and I'm able to reach the value of `reportUrl`. I tested with echo statements. Any thoughts?

Am I not exiting the parallel statement properly?

```
stage("Deploy") {

  def deployments = [:]

  // Code here not pasted

  parallel deployments

  echo "Deployed to clusters"
}


  stage('Reporting') {
    def reportUrl = 'https://testurl'
    echo "${reportUrl}"


    sh """
      ./my-tool report deploy \
        --report-url "${reportUrl}" \
        --force
    """
  }
```

**EDIT 6/22**

reportUrl comes from a groovy file: example.groovy

`example = load("deploy/example.groovy")`

`def reportUrl = example.REPORT_URL['report']`

`//I can see the url being pulled correctly here`

`echo "${reportUrl}"`

Comment: It would be useful to see where teamsUrl comes from. We can't see it on your snippet.

Comment: It comes from a groovy file. See edit above